# GWT can't define canvas on existing element

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, canvas

I have an element defined as a `HTML` element, namely `<canvas id = 'foo' width = '25' height = '40'></canvas>`. I am trying to draw to it like this:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
Canvas canvas2 = Canvas.createIfSupported();
Element el = DOM.getElementById("foo");
canvas2.setElement(el);
```

The last line is throwing an error in Eclipse, error message being **The method setElement(Element) from the type UIObject is not visible**. What should I do to correct it? This is the list of classes I am importing, is there any `JAR` conflict?

```
import com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas;
import com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context2d;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
```

Comment: Most likely you have some JAR conflicts in your classpath. Make sure you don't have duplicate JARs, (both in Eclipse project libraries and in your run time classpath).

Comment: method setElement() for Canvas in GWT is protected, so you might have problems to access it

Comment: So how do I access a `Canvas` element defined as HTML, and write to it?

Comment: A good way to develop with GWT is to avoid entirely javascript and HTML... You only use Java code (even to build the UI structure). That way, you rarely need to query for Elements by Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this currently. [Issue #6683](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6683) is open for that in GWT's issue tracker. The suggested workaround is to copy the Canvas widget class and loose the visibility of the constructor... not very convenient I admit.